# How to stop the Nav pane scrolling down to current/default folder in Win10 File Explorer & Save/Open File Dialogs?

Tags: windows-explorer, navigation

I have this minor but annoying issue where the **Windows 10 File Explorer Navigation Pane keeps always scrolling to the middle or the bottom**. Actually, it scrolls to the current/default folder.

It is quite annoying since you never know where will the Nav Pane be, and the Quick Access folders are usually out of view because of this unwanted scroll down. What's the point to have Quick Access folders that are always hidden?

This is not about the option "Expand to open folder" from Folder Options. The **folders in the Nav Pane are not expanded, but the Nav Pane is scrolled down** to the current/default folder.

A partial, dirty solution is Folder Option > Open File Explorer to > Quick Access. This makes the File explorer open always to Quick Access, so the Nav Pane is scrolled to the top. This is not the correct/ideal solution. **I guess it's correct for the Nav Pane to scroll to the open folder when the option "expand the open folder" is active, yet this should not happen when this option is disabled**.

This unwanted Nav Pane scroll happens on file explorer (any folder) as well as Open/Save File dialog boxes.

Comment: Even though you don't have `Expand to open folder` set, it sounds like you have `Show all folders` selected (and numerous folders on the Desktop), otherwise it's hard to imagine the collapsed NavPane with enough items to require scrolling. Is that the case? Does un-checking `Show all folders` help?